# Is this way of pooling Kaplan-Meier estimates correct? Example made with R mice::pool_scalar

Tags: survival, data-transformation, cox-model, multiple-imputation

This is my data. It has no gaps in survival or the used predictor - for the sake simplicity in this example. I want to see, if multiply generated the same dataset will give - after pooling - the same results as the raw approach.

Of course my REAL data will have some gaps. The gaps will occur in a few variables, used to derive the survival (=success) status, which is a compound endpoint. After the imputation the status will vary a bit between the samples. Times will be always the same.

So this my exemplary data. Not much meaningful, but suffices:

```
surv_data <- as.data.frame(list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3,5,2,4,5,1), 
                            status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0), 
                            x=c(0,2,1,1,3,2,0,1,1,2,0,1), 
                            sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0)))
```

Let's "impute" (nothing will be imputed, just generated) 10 identical datasets. All will have same survival, time, and sex.

```
imp <- mice(surv_data,m=10)
```

Now I will perform the fake analysis and pool the results by hand, using the `pool_scalar()` function from the mice package.

```
km_imp <- with(imp, with(summary(survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex), times = 1:5, extend = TRUE),
                          data.frame(strata, time, surv, std.err, lower, upper)))

> km_imp$analyses %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(strata, time) %>% 
  summarize(pooled = data.frame(pool.scalar(Q=surv, U=std.err^2, n=12, k = 1)[c("qbar", "t")])) %>% 
  unpack(pooled) %>% 
  mutate(surv=qbar, SE = sqrt(t), LCI = qbar - 1.96*SE, UCI=qbar + 1.96*SE)

   strata  time  qbar      t  surv    SE     LCI   UCI
   <fct>  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 sex=0      1 0.857 0.0175 0.857 0.132  0.598  1.12 
 2 sex=0      2 0.643 0.0443 0.643 0.210  0.230  1.06 
 3 sex=0      3 0.429 0.0503 0.429 0.224 -0.0110 0.868
 4 sex=0      4 0.214 0.0355 0.214 0.188 -0.155  0.584
 5 sex=0      5 0.214 0.0355 0.214 0.188 -0.155  0.584
 6 sex=1      1 1     0      1     0      1      1    
 7 sex=1      2 0.6   0.048  0.6   0.219  0.171  1.03 
 8 sex=1      3 0.6   0.048  0.6   0.219  0.171  1.03 
 9 sex=1      4 0.3   0.057  0.3   0.239 -0.168  0.768
10 sex=1      5 0.3   0.057  0.3   0.239 -0.168  0.768
```

The bounds of the CI exceed 1 or 0, but that's natural for normal approximation. Will handle it later via log or log-log CIs.

and the data from the raw function - no imputation, no pooling:

```
> with(summary(survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data=surv_data, conf.type="plain"), times = 1:5, extend = TRUE),
+      data.frame(strata, time, surv, lower, upper))
   strata time   surv  lower  upper
1   sex=0    1 0.8571 0.5979 1.0000
2   sex=0    2 0.6429 0.2304 1.0000
3   sex=0    3 0.4286 0.0000 0.8681
4   sex=0    4 0.2143 0.0000 0.5837
5   sex=0    5 0.2143 0.0000 0.5837
6   sex=1    1 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
7   sex=1    2 0.6000 0.1706 1.0000
8   sex=1    3 0.6000 0.1706 1.0000
9   sex=1    4 0.3000 0.0000 0.7679
10  sex=1    5 0.3000 0.0000 0.7679
```

But besides, if we pretend >1 = 1, and <0 = 0, then they fully agree.
Let me also try the log-log, to avoid these artefacts.

```
km_imp$analyses %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(surv_log = log(-log(surv))) %>%
  group_by(strata, time) %>% 
  summarize(pooled = data.frame(pool.scalar(Q=surv_log, U=std.err^2, n=12, k = 1)[c("qbar", "t")])) %>% 
  unpack(pooled) %>% 
  mutate(surv=exp(-exp(qbar)), SE = (sqrt(t)/surv)/log(surv), 
         LCI = exp(-exp(qbar - 1.96*SE)) , UCI=exp(-exp(qbar + 1.96*SE)))
```

giving:

```
  strata  time     qbar        t  surv      SE       LCI     UCI
   <fct>  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 sex=0      1   -1.87    0.0175 0.857  -1.00    0.334     0.979
 2 sex=0      2   -0.817   0.0443 0.643  -0.741   0.151     0.902
 3 sex=0      3   -0.166   0.0503 0.429  -0.618   0.0583    0.777
 4 sex=0      4    0.432   0.0355 0.214  -0.571   0.00894   0.605
 5 sex=0      5    0.432   0.0355 0.214  -0.571   0.00894   0.605
 6 sex=1      1 -Inf     NaN      1     NaN     NaN       NaN    
 7 sex=1      2   -0.672   0.048  0.6    -0.715   0.126     0.882
 8 sex=1      3   -0.672   0.048  0.6    -0.715   0.126     0.882
 9 sex=1      4    0.186   0.057  0.3    -0.661   0.0123    0.719
10 sex=1      5    0.186   0.057  0.3    -0.661   0.0123    0.719
```

vs.

```
with(summary(survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data=surv_data, conf.type="log-log"), times = 1:5, extend = TRUE),
     data.frame(strata, time, surv, lower, upper))

 strata time   surv    lower  upper
1   sex=0    1 0.8571 0.334054 0.9786
2   sex=0    2 0.6429 0.151467 0.9017
3   sex=0    3 0.4286 0.058274 0.7768
4   sex=0    4 0.2143 0.008937 0.6047
5   sex=0    5 0.2143 0.008937 0.6047
6   sex=1    1 1.0000 1.000000 1.0000
7   sex=1    2 0.6000 0.125730 0.8818
8   sex=1    3 0.6000 0.125730 0.8818
9   sex=1    4 0.3000 0.012302 0.7192
10  sex=1    5 0.3000 0.012302 0.7192
```

All fine, but my question is: **isn't this too naive, to simplistic?** In the real case I will have data with gaps, the imputed datasets won't be same. I read somewhere, that the **complementary log-log** should be applied to survival probabilities, to pool survival probability with Rubin's rules. But cloglog and log-log are just the mirrors:
[image]

What's your opinion and can you give some example of solution, example?

---

I was provided with this [reference](https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2017/SP/PharmaSUG-2017-SP05.pdf). My mistake was that I didn't transformed the variance passed to the imputation method.

The code is in SAS, but I translated it to R, hope without mistakes. I currently have no access to SAS to validate it numerically. If you find any, please let me know in a comment! Maybe someone will find this code useful.

```
km_imp1$analyses %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(K = log(-log(surv)),
         U = std.err^2 / (surv * log(surv))^2 )  %>%
  group_by(strata, time) %>% 
  summarize(pooled = data.frame(pool.scalar(Q=K, U=U, n=Inf, k = 1)[c("qbar", "t")])) %>% 
  unpack(pooled) %>% 
  mutate(surv = exp(-exp(qbar)), 
         SE   = abs(sqrt(t)*surv*log(surv)), 
         LCI = surv^(exp(1.96*SE)), UCI=surv^(exp(-1.96*SE)))
```

and the result:

```
  strata  time    qbar      t  surv     SE   LCI   UCI
  <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 trt=1      3 -4.23   1.00   0.986 0.0144 0.985 0.986
2 trt=1     50 -0.952  0.0461 0.680 0.0563 0.650 0.708
3 trt=1    100 -0.372  0.0307 0.502 0.0606 0.460 0.542
4 trt=2      3 -3.10   0.333  0.956 0.0249 0.954 0.958
5 trt=2     50 -0.541  0.0343 0.559 0.0602 0.520 0.596
6 trt=2    100  0.0959 0.0249 0.333 0.0578 0.292 0.374
```

Now I'm double confused. I found this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4517373/

and implemented it:

```
km_imp1$analyses %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(K = log(-log(1-surv)),
         U = std.err^2 / ((1-surv) * log(1-surv))^2 )  %>%
  group_by(strata, time) %>% 
  summarize(pooled = data.frame(pool.scalar(Q=K, U=U, n=Inf, k = 1)[c("qbar", "t")])) %>% 
  unpack(pooled) %>% 
  mutate(surv = 1-exp(-exp(qbar)), 
         SE   = sqrt(t), 
         LCI = 1-exp(-exp(qbar - 1.96*SE)),
         UCI = 1-exp(-exp(qbar + 1.96*SE)))

  strata  time   qbar      t  surv    SE   LCI   UCI
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 trt=1      3  1.44  0.0550 0.986 0.234 0.931 0.999
2 trt=1     50  0.130 0.0239 0.680 0.154 0.569 0.786
3 trt=1    100 -0.361 0.0305 0.502 0.175 0.390 0.625
4 trt=2      3  1.14  0.0327 0.956 0.181 0.888 0.988
5 trt=2     50 -0.201 0.0278 0.559 0.167 0.446 0.678
6 trt=2    100 -0.905 0.0458 0.333 0.214 0.233 0.459
```

The results are now different. Be careful when implementing these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to find a transformation that makes estimates most closely follow a normal distribution, so that Rubin's rules can be used for pooling among models built on multiply imputed data sets. [Stef van Buuren recommends](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-pooling.html) (based on literature citations*) the complementary log-log transformation for survival *probabilities*, and a log transformation for survival *distributions* or hazard ratios.

There's a potential ambiguity in the use of "complementary log-log" in a survival model. The survival function is the complement of the corresponding probability distribution function. When `survfit.formula()` uses a "log-log" confidence interval, that's `log(-log(survival))`. But that's the same as the *complementary* log-log transformation of the corresponding probability distribution.

[Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) discuss different transformations on pages 16-17. They conclude: "as long as one avoids the 'plain' intervals, all of the options work well." That's consistent with what you show.

One is never sure that a generic recommendation holds in any specific application. In multiple imputation, you can start with the generic recommendation and evaluate the corresponding distribution of transformed estimates directly among large numbers of imputed data sets. If one transformation doesn't work adequately, try another.

---

*Upon review, the [citation](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10198-008-0129-y) that van Buuren provides for these transformations doesn't seem to mention any transformations at all! Nevertheless, the proposed transformations make sense based on the underlying subject matter. [This](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/9/57) is the correct link, provided in a [comment by David Luke Theissen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581063/draw-survival-curves-of-2-groups-after-multiple-imputation-on-covariates#comment1073515_581063) on a similar question.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes a lot of sense with the cloglog vs. log-log! I made an update, but I'm unable to validate it in SAS (having the macro in the attached PDF from PharmaSUG). Now the results don't match exactly the analysis using just the single occurrence of the same dataset, but I guess it's due to the transformed variance passed to the imputation procedure. I have to find a way and validate it somewhere.
  https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2017/SP/PharmaSUG-2017-SP05.pdf

Comment: @GeneralizedLM I just re-discovered an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168742/28500) to a related question from 2015. It provides a [link to a publication](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/15/54) that implements this in R via `mice`. Should be useful for double-checking; at first glance it looks very similar to what was proposed for SAS. Also, as you seem to be fluent in tidyverse, you might consider writing a `broom::tidy` method, as indicated on the help page for `mice::pool`.

Comment: Thank you so much! In the meantime, I found exactly the same, only at a different place : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4517373/
The formulas here are different (with 1-S). I implemented it and got different results... What a mess :( I updated my answer above.

Comment: @GeneralizedLM the [Marshall et al reference](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/9/57) cited to support the `cloglog` transformation refers to the 1999 Hosmer and Lemeshow text as the source. The second edition of that text uses the transformation with `S(t)` rather than the `(1-S(t))` form adopted by [Morisot et al.](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/15/54). As I interpret that, if one uses Hosmer and Lemeshow as the citation for a `cloglog` transformation, that is intended to be in terms of the associated probability distribution, _not_ the survival function.

Comment: @GeneralizedLM the important point is to find a transformation that leads to a near-normal distribution of the estimates. I suppose that either transformation could work in some circumstances. Make sure to use the appropriate variance estimate for whichever one you choose.